# Limit number of connection to MySQL database using JDBC driver in spark

Tags: mysql, apache-spark, jdbc, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am currently importing data from a MySQL database into spark using the JDBC driver using the following command in pyspark:

```
dataframe_mysql = sqlctx
    .read
    .format("jdbc")
    .option("url", "jdbc:mysql://<IP-ADDRESS>:3306/<DATABASE>")
    .option("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
    .option("dbtable", "<TABLE>")
    .option("user", "<USER>")
    .option("password","<PASSWORD>")
    .load()
```

When I run the spark job, I get the following error message:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException (Too many connections).

It seems that since several nodes are attempting to connect concurrently to the database, I am exceeding **MySQL's connection limit (151)** and this is causing my job to run slower.

How can I limit the number of connections that the JDBC driver uses in pyspark? Any help would be great!

Comment: Why not raise the limit? 151 isn't many. Mine is 1000 and I confidently expect to have  to raise it. Hope to, actually, as the business develops.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [numPartitions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html) param. According to the documentation it is the maximum number of partitions that can be used for parallelism in table reading and writing. This also determines the maximum number of concurrent JDBC connections. If the number of partitions to write exceeds this limit, then there is a decrease to this limit by calling coalesce(numPartitions) before writing.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should reduce the default partition size, or reduce the number of executors.